# Node.js send input to docker container on spawned ssh connected

Tags: node.js, docker, ssh

I'm am trying to automatically send an input to a process (docker container) on a remote VM. I'm able to connect to the machine and attach to the container. But then I need to send the input to the stdin of the container. However I cannot detect when is the node.js connected to the container and when is okay to send input.

```js
const cmd = 'sudo docker attach --detach-keys="ctrl-x" app';
const child = spawn("ssh", [`-t`, "-v", `-i`, keypath, user + "@" + host, cmd], {
    stdio: ["pipe", "inherit", "inherit"],
});
child.stdin.write("some input to send to the container\n");
```

So how can I know when to execute the `.write(...)` ? I guess I need some event on something, but not sure what could help.

Or maybe I could send the command directly to the container using ssh. Is there any way?

Thanks.

Comment: Scripting a command-line request, inside scripted `sudo`, inside a remote `ssh` connection, seems a little indirect; can your service expose something like an HTTP endpoint that you can make a direct request to?

Comment: It seems more secure to allow acces only through ssh than expose system-level operations through HTTP

Comment: ...but giving sudo permission to a script is okay?  Remember, if you can `docker` anything, you can edit arbitrary host files as root too.  I would not recommend scripting `docker exec`, especially if you're thinking about the security aspects of it.